# Find gender of AD/LDAP-User

Tags: active-directory, ldap

there is a field/column, in ActiveDirectory, that returns the gender / sex of the ~person~?

I need this for a inHouse Email-Generator with Title
=> Dear Mr Barton | Dear Mrs Romanoff

the givenName, sn are do only returns the names!?

thanks

Comment: AD contains only what you put into it. How do you expect it to automatically obtain the gender of a person? There is, however, a `personalTitle` attribute available if you want to populate it.

Comment: Okay, I figured as much. i thought, maybe there is a hidden field which contains e.g. a number or a cryptic character 0 => woman, 1 => man. Unfortunately, an IT provider fills this with us and I have no exact overview of the process. But I now have a list of names and gender... that could work http://www.albertmartin.de/vornamen/?name=&f=1&m=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't something you want to guess at. People aren't fond of you getting their gender wrong.

If you guess based on their first name, you'll be wrong sometimes. Many first names are used for both men and women. In your link with the names, look for the names marked with a star (like Lindsay, Morgan, Sasha, Jody, etc.).

Plus, at least in English, women use different titles depending on their marital status (Mrs, Miss, Ms). Or you might have some PhD's who prefer you address them by Dr.

Phylogenesis (in the comments) has the right idea. Use the `personalTitle` attribute to store the title. It'll be difficult to populate that for all of your accounts, but that's the only way to do this right without ever being wrong.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you 100%. That is exactly what we will do. Unfortunately we have to find an interim solution until then. I hope the data will be updated by our HumanRessources in the near future. 1000 Thanks